# Mapael update trigger

Tags: javascript, raphael, javascript-objects, mapael

So essentially I am working with a large dataset and don't want to have to define every area for every year. But when I update to the next year it only appends the data to the map leaving the rest there to be shown in the legend.

I tried using replaceOptions and it just turns the map gray and it becomes unresponsive.

There has to be something easy I am overlooking.

It also seems to not be working entirely correct when I update the year. As some I click on a county to show that data and it will give me a javascript error of:
main.js.php:85 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Even though the data is in the object. I have it set to console log and can search for what it should display and it's there.

Any help would be appreciated. You can check out the project here. It is for a nonprofit.

Thanks

http://192.249.112.63/~uofimap/

Comment: I think you probably need to get some of it onto a jsfiddle or similar to test for the error, so people can edit easier. It may also be useful just to add a bit more info to the first sentence description, as it's not entirely clear.